# Proofs from Ch. 1 of Arnold's ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I've started reading Vladimir Arnold's *Ordinary Differential Equations* on my own.  I like it so far, the only problem is that all of the exercises (as yet) are of the type "prove $X$" and without an instructor or TA to grade me, I have no idea if I'm proving these things correctly and rigorously.  I'm hoping you guys can let me know where I've made mistakes and where I can improve the language to sound a bit more professional.

I provided relevant definitions at the bottom.

> Problem 2 (pg 4): Prove that a one-parameter group of transformations is a commutative group and that every mapping $g^t: M \to M$ is one-to-one.

Proof: Let's start with proving that this is a commutative group:

1. Closure: $g^rg^s=g^{r+s}$ by definition.  $r+s \in \Bbb R$, thus $g^{r+s} \in \{g^t \mid t \in \Bbb R\}$ for all $r,s \in \Bbb R$.
2. Associativity: $(g^rg^s)g^t=g^{r+s}g^t=g^{(r+s)+t} = g^{r+(s+t)}=g^rg^{s+t}=g^r(g^sg^t)$.
3. Identity Element: $g^0$ is the identity element because $g^tg^0 = g^{t+0} = g^t$ and $g^0g^t=g^{0+t}=g^t$.
4. Inverse Element: Because $t\in \Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R$ is an abelian group wrt addition, there exists a $-t$ for every $t$.  Then I just show that $(g^t)^{-1}=g^{-t}$ because $g^tg^{-t} = g^{t+-t}=g^0$ and $g^{-t}g^t=g^{-t+t}=g^0$.
5. Commutativity: $g^tg^s = g^{t+s} = g^{s+t} = g^sg^t$.

Now I'll prove that every element of this group is one-to-one.  I never know if one-to-one means injective or bijective.  I'm pretty sure these functions are bijective, though, so that's what I'll try to prove.

First injectivity:

Because there exists an inverse element $g^{-t}$ for every mapping $g^t$ and because the image of $g^t$ is in $M$ (because the codomain *is* $M$), we can see that $$g^tx=g^ty \implies g^{-t}g^tx=g^{-t}g^ty \implies x=y$$ thus these functions are injective.

Now surjectivity:

Consider an arbitrary element $y \in M$.  I need to show that there exists an $x\in M$ s.t. $g^tx=y$.  I propose $x=g^{-t}y$ because then $g^t(g^{-t}y) = g^tg^{-t}y = g^0y=y$.  I know that $x=g^{-t}y$ can always be chosen because $g^{-t}$ exists (as proven above) and because $y\in M = \operatorname{domain}(g^{-t})$.

Because $g^t$ is injective and surjective, it must be bijective.$\ \ \ \ \ \square$

> Problem 3 (pg 5): Prove that there is one and only one phase curve passing through every point of phase space.

Proof: To prove that there is *one* phase curve passing through every point of phase space means that there should exist a $t\in \Bbb R$ and an $x\in M$ s.t. $g^tx=y,\ \forall y \in M$.  But I already proved that $g^t$ is surjective on $M$ above so this is true.

Next I prove that there is *only one* phase curve passing through every point of phase space.   I think what need to prove here is that if $y\in \{g^tx_1\}$ and $y\in \{g^tx_2\}$ then $x_2 \in \{g^tx_1\}$.  Because $y\in \{g^tx_1\}$ and $y\in \{g^tx_2\}$, there exists $t_1, t_2 \in \Bbb R$ s.t.
$$g^{t_1}x_1=y=g^{t_2}x_2$$
This implies that $x_2 = g^{-t_2}g^{t_1}x_1 = g^{t_1-t_2}x_1$. Therefore $x_2 \in \{g^tx_1\}$.$\ \ \ \ \ \square$

> Problem 4 (pg 5): Prove that there is one and only one integral curve passing through every point of extended phase space.

Proof: First I prove that there exists an integral curve passing through every point $(t_0,x_0)\in \Bbb R \times M$.  Consider the arbitrary integral curve $\{(t,g^tx) \in \Bbb R \times M\}$.  Because $t$ is unrestricted, this really means that there exists an $x\in M$ s.t. $g^tx=x_0$ for every $x_0\in M$.  But this just means that the function $g^t$ is surjective on $M$ which was proven above.

Next I prove that there is a unique integral curve passing through every point of extended phase space.  Not only is $g^t$ surjective on $M$, it is injective.  Meaning if $g^tx=x_0$ and $g^tx' = x_0$, then $x=x'$.  Thus for every $(t_0,x_0)\in \Bbb R\times M$, there is only one $x\in M$ s.t. $g^{t_0}x=x_0$.  This then means that there is only one integral curve $\{(t,g^tx)\}$ containing the point $(t_0,x_0)$.$\ \ \ \ \ \ \square$

> Problem 5 (pg 5): Prove that the horizontal line $\Bbb R \times x,\ x\in M$ is an integral curve if and only if $x$ is an equilibrium position.

Proof: $$\Bbb R\times x = \{(t,g^ty)\in \Bbb R\times M \mid t\in \Bbb R\ \&\ g^ty=x\}$$
But $g^ty=x$ for all $t$ means that $g^0y=x$.  Which implies $y=x$.  Which implies $g^tx=x$.  Which implies $x$ is an equilibrium position.$\ \ \ \ \ \square$

> Problem 6 (pg 5): Prove that a shift $$\begin{matrix}h^s: (\Bbb R \times M) \to (\Bbb R \times M), & h^s(t,x)=(t+s,x)\end{matrix}$$ of extended phase space along the time axis carries integral curves into integral curves.

Proof: Consider an arbitrary integral curve $A=\{(t,g^tx)\}$.  The image of $A$ under $h^s$ is $$\{h^s(t,g^tx)\} = \{(t+s,g^tx\} = \{(r,g^{r-s}x)\} = \{r,g^r(g^{-s}x)\} = \{r,g^ry\}$$ for $r=s+t$ and $y=g^{-s}x$.  But this is just an integral curve.  Thus $h^s$ takes integrals curves to integral curves.$\ \ \ \ \ \square$.

---

**Definition:** A family $\{g^t\}$ of mappings of a set $M$ into itself, is called a *one-parameter group of transformations* of $M$ if $g^{t+s}=g^tg^s$ for all $s,t \in \Bbb R$ and $g^0$ is the identity mapping.

**Definition:** A pair $(M,\{g^t\})$ consisting of a set $M$ and a one-parameter group $\{g^t\}$ of transformations of $M$ into itself is called a *phase flow*.

**Definition:** The set $M$ is called the *phase space* of the flow.

**Definition:** The image of $\Bbb R$ under mapping $$\begin{matrix}\varphi: \Bbb R \to M, & \varphi(t)=g^tx\end{matrix}$$ is called a *phase curve* of the flow $(M, \{g^t\})$.

**Definition:** By the *extended phase space* of a flow $(M, \{g^t\})$ is meant the direct product $\Bbb R\times M$ (I think Arnold is using direct product to mean Cartesian product) of the real $t$-axis and the phase space $M$.

**Definition:** The graph of the function $$\begin{matrix}\varphi: \Bbb R \to M, & \varphi(t)=g^tx\end{matrix}$$ is called an *integral curve* of the flow $(M, \{g^t\})$.

**Definition:** By an *equilibrium position* $x\in M$ of a flow $(M,\{g^t\})$ is meant a phase point which is itself a phase curve:
$$\begin{matrix}g^tx=x & \forall t\in\Bbb R\end{matrix}$$

Comment: For part 2 of Problem 3, is it not enough to state: 
$y\in \{g^tx_1\}$ and $y\in \{g^tx_2\} \implies g^{t_1}x_1 = g^{t_2}x_2 = y.$ Hence $\forall t_1 \in \mathbb{R}, g^{t_1}x_1 \in \{g^tx_1\} \implies g^{t_1}x_1 \in \{g^tx_2\}$ and so by definition of subsets $\{g^tx_1\} \subseteq \{g^tx_2\}.$ The same argument can be made for the reverse case and thus $\{g^tx_1\}=\{g^tx_2\}$.